# PostgreSQL query that finds and/or deletes certain elements from JSON array field

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

We have a table with a `jsonb[]` column that has an array of `JSON` objects with various keys. The DB is PostgreSQL (v9.6)

```
----------------------------------------------------
| id | data (jsonb[])                              |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1 | [{a:1, B:2, c:3}, {a:4, c:5}, {a:6, B:7}]   |
|  2 | [{a:8}, {B:9, c:10}]                        |
|  3 | [{a:11}]                                    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

We'd like to remove or set to empty all the values of **B:**

so, we'd like to get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| id | data (jsonb[])                                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | [{a:1, B:null/"", c:3}, {a:4, c:5}, {a:6, B:null/""}]  |
|  2 | [{a:8}, {B:null/"", c:10}]                             |
|  3 | [{a:11}]                                               |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
------------------------------------------
| id | data (jsonb[])                    |
------------------------------------------
|  1 | [{a:1, c:3}, {a:4, c:5}, {a:6}]   |
|  2 | [{a:8}, {c:10}]                   |
|  3 | [{a:11}]                          |
------------------------------------------
```

If there is no simple way to update the B field, we'd be happy to find a way to get all records that have B: in data field, in that case, we can load all the record and process them outside DB.

So far we can't find a way to do it, not even to find all records that have the B: field.

Any ideas will be great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by `UNNEST Array` --> `Subtract Element` --> `Aggregate` approach

If you want to remove the Element then try this:

```
select 
id,
jsonb_agg(y-'B') 
from test cross join lateral unnest(data) x(y)
group by id
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e5be28cc5c7a3db8d9ddec9477409165)

If you want to set the value of element `NULL` then try this:

```
select 
id, 
jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(y,'{B}','null',false)) 
from test cross join lateral unnest(data) x(y)
group by id
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=dc45dd2e58e9f62ae7c133d9db53ca1b)

**EDIT as per Comment:**

```
with cte as (
select 
id,
array_agg(y-'B') "data"
from test cross join lateral unnest(data) x(y)
group by id
)

update test t1 set data = t2.data from cte t2 where t1.id=t2.id;
```

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=69bf8c1ba73066748dc2d866847cb79c)

Comment: Thank you, it's great, but it's only removing the B: key from the select. I'd like to remove it from the database...